# How to use page directive in jsp using netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, jsp-tags, page-directives

I am trying to run a .jsp project in Netbeans 7.1, here I have 2 .java file under default package like this -

```
FriendzAvenue
|
...Web Pages
|  |
|  +....META-INF
|  +....WEB-INF
|  .....Login.jsp
|
...Source Packages
   |
   ...<default package>
      |
      ...ConnectionPool.java
      ...MyFunction.java
```

Now, how can import these 2 file in my Login.jsp file, I can't understand what to write in this line of code -

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*, java.io.*"%>
```

Comment: firstly use a package ,secondly you need to put your compiled class files in   the classes directory under WEB-INF and then use import attribute in the `page` directive

Comment: @Ramanlfc What to write in .java file for package line - `package ????;
`import java.io.PrintStream;
`import java.sql.*;`  and for `<%@ page import="java.sql.*, java.io.*,??"%>`

Comment: since `ConnectionPool.java` and `MyFunction.java` don't have a package , you can't use import attribute in the page directive